# Pull GitHub repository using Bazel

Tags: github, bazel

I need to download an entire GitHub repository using [Bazel](https://bazel.build/). Since I'm quite new to this tool I'm not really sure how to achieve that.

My main idea is this:

write a custom repository rule in **downloadgithubrepo.bzl** (which is located in the project root just like the WORKSPACE file) such as:

```
def _impl(repository_ctx):
    repository_ctx.download("url_to_zipped_github_repo", output='relative_path_to_output_file')

github = repository_rule(
    implementation = _impl
```

and in the **WORKSPACE** file to write something like this:

```
load("//:downloadgithubrepo.bzl", "github")
```

and to invoke a build a **BUILD** file is needed (also located at the project root)
its contents are the following:

```
cc_library(
    name = "testrun",
    srcs = "main.c",
)
```

I had to add the main.c file otherwise the build is failing - that is one issue and the real issue is that this does not work, as in the build is passing but the GitHub repository is not downloaded.

Am I on the right path at all?? Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you're looking might already be implemented in the [`new_git_repository`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#new_git_repository) repository rule, or the [`git_repository`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#git_repository) rule if the GitHub project already has Bazel `BUILD` files wired in.

If the GitHub project does *not* have BUILD files, a BUILD file is required when using `new_git_repository`. For example, if you want to depend on a [**file target** (e.g. `/foo/bar.txt`) or **rule target** (e.g. a `cc_library`)](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html#targets) in `https://github.com/example/repository`, and the repository **does not** have BUILD files, write these lines in your project's `WORKSPACE` file:

```
new_git_repository(
    name = "example_repository",
    remote = "https://github.com/example/repository.git",
    build_file_content = """
exports_files(["foo/bar.txt"])

# you can also create targets
cc_library(
    name = "remote_cc_library",
    srcs = ["..."],
    hdrs = ["..."],
)
""",
)
```

In your `BUILD` file, reference the external repository's targets using the `@` prefix:

```
cc_library(
    name = "testrun",
    srcs = ["main.c"],
    data = ["@example_repository//:foo/bar.txt"],
    deps = ["@example_repository//:remote_cc_library"],
)
```

When you run `bazel build //:testrun`, Bazel will..

1. Analyze the dependencies of `//:testrun`, which include the file `main.c` and targets from the external repository `@example_repository`.
2. Look up the WORKSPACE file for an external repository named `example_repository`, and finds the `new_git_repository` declaration.
3. Perform a `git clone` on the `remote` attribute specified in the `example_repository` declaration.
4. Write a BUILD file containing the `build_file_content` string at the project root of the cloned repository.
5. Analyze the targets `@example_repository//:foo/bar.txt` and `@example_repository//:remote_cc_library`
6. Build the dependencies, and hands them to your `//:testrun` `cc_library`.
7. Build `//:testrun`.

If the GitHub project **does have** BUILD files, you do not need to provide an BUILD file. You can refer to the targets directly after specifying the WORKSPACE dependency with `git_repository`:

```
git_repository(
    name = "example_repository",
    remote = "https://github.com/example/repository.git",
)
```

For more information, check out Bazel's documentation on [External Repositories](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html#depending-on-non-bazel-projects).

Comment: Thank you Jin.
I'm sorry for the delayed response.
Your answer is helpful and I have accepted it.

Comment: I think there is a missing closing ")" before the closing """. Other than that, worked great!