# Using Bazel module extensions in BUILD files?

Tags: bazel

I am trying to add Github repo dependencies, which aren't Bazel projects themselves, to a Bazel build by following [this doc](https://bazel.build/external/migration#fetch-deps-module-extensions). How does one use module extensions in Bazel to link external Github repos? I found [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592846/pull-github-repository-using-bazel) that diagrams using `new_github_repository`, but this doesn't seem to be covered in the new [module extensions doc](https://bazel.build/external/extension).

For reference, [this is the Github repo](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp/tree/v1.4.0) I was hoping to build on top of and use `whisper.h` in.

This is my `MODULE.bazel` file:

```
## MODULE.bazel
module(
    name = "test",
)

non_module_dependencies = use_extension("//:deps.bzl", "data_deps_ext")
use_repo(non_module_dependencies, "whisper")
```

This is my `deps.bzl` file:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")

def whisper():
    git_repository(
        name = "whisper",
        remote = "https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp.git",
        tag = "v1.4.0"
    )

def _data_deps_extension_impl(_):
    whisper()

data_deps_ext = module_extension(
    implementation = _data_deps_extension_impl,
)
```

And this is my main BUILD:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cc"],
    deps = [
        "@whisper"
    ]
)
```

However, running the BUILD gives me this error:

```
DEBUG: Repository _main~data_deps_ext~whisper instantiated at:
  callstack not available
Repository rule git_repository defined at:
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_victor/1cabe6594cc48c856544c639052f58cd/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:181:33: in <toplevel>
ERROR: /Users/victor/Desktop/Check/cpp/main/BUILD:1:10: no such package '@_main~data_deps_ext~whisper//': BUILD file not found in directory '' of external repository @_main~data_deps_ext~whisper. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package. and referenced by '//main:main'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//main:main' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 5.239s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (52 packages loaded, 211 targets configured)
    Fetching repository @bazel_tools~cc_configure_extension~local_config_cc; Running xcode-locatorlysis of target '//main:main' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 5.239s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (52 packages loaded, 211 targets configured)
    Fetching repository @bazel_tools~cc_configure_extension~local_config_cc; Running xcode-locator
```

I'm not sure how to reference the module extension in the BUILD file itself? I assume it needs to be listed as a dependency?